# Routing Table: Why do some websites still work after removing the default entry?

Tags: networking

i have a question regarding routing tables. By default the *ip route* command gives me the following result:

```
default via 192.168.178.1 dev wlp6s0  proto static  metric 600 
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp6s0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlp6s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.178.62  metric 600
```

192.168.178.1 is the adress of my router. Now, when i delete the default entry the routing table looks like this.

```
169.254.0.0/16 dev wlp6s0  scope link  metric 1000 
192.168.178.0/24 dev wlp6s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.178.62  metric 600
```

If i understand it correctly this means that i should only be able to send packets to devices inside the local network because there is no route defined for other destinations right?

When i try to open a website in firefox now it usually tells me that it is unable to connect as expected but there are some websites like google.com which still work in firefox. However, i can't ping google.com because i get the error *connect: Network is unreachable*

To sum it up, i want to know why some websites still work after i removed the default entry in the routing table while others don't.

Comment: You sure they worked?  Did you close your browser entirely, wipe your browser cache, and try again?  Web browsers are *notorious* for caching things, and usually caching is to blame in these instances.

Comment: Yes im sure. Youtube works as well and i can watch videos that i haven't watched before and using vlc to stream youtube videos works too

Comment: and you are sure you only have v4 routes, and no IPv6 routes? `ip -6 route list`

Comment: Yes you are right it is the IPv6 routes. I feel so stupid now but thank you very much!

Comment: Glad it helped.  I posted my comment as an answer, feel free to accept it since it helped to identify the issue you ran into, and how to resolve it (delete the v6 route)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be the case where you have two IP routes - one for IPv4 which you removed and the other for IPv6.

Check `ip -6 route list` to find any IPv6 routes, and if there is a default v6 route, delete it.  Then you will get the behavior you expect.